# How to create new instance on interface static method in Java 8?

Tags: java, interface, static, java-8

I want to enforce with an interface a static method that creates a new instance implementing the interface, fills it with the requested value, and returns it.

My question is how to code the interface such that when there is no implementation of the class the method cannot be called.

Example:

```
public interface IMemoryCell {

    public static ? memoryCellCreator(int val)
    {
        return ?;           
    }

    public abstract int getVal();

    public abstract void setVal(int val);

}
```

Comment: Don't you have to make the method default? (As in the keyword missing in your question mark) I'm not sure I think that's what it was though.

Comment: You mean you're trying to create an instance of an arbitrary class that implements the interface?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, correct.

Comment: @jundl77 Thank you, but - no, on static you don't need it, Please have a look on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: Java 8 allows static methods in interfaces.  Write a public static factory method that instantiates an implementation and returns it.

Comment: @BrianGoetz you are correct, and this was my original question, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This one works, although I am curious about the use case where you need this:

```
public interface IMemoryCell {
    static IMemoryCell instance(int val) {
        final IMemoryCell inst = new IMemoryCell() {
            private int v;

            {
                this.v = val;
            }

            @Override
            public int getVal() {
                return this.v;
            }

            @Override
            public void setVal(int val) {
                this.v = val;
            }
        };
        return inst;
    }

    public int getVal();

    public void setVal(int val);
}
```

Comment: OP is looking to return an instance of classes that implements the interface.

Comment: You cal also do `return new MemoryCell(val);` as well from the method. Of course, assuming MemoryCell implements IMemoryCell.

Comment: Then you're limited to only a single class that implements the interface, which also seems counter to what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, that is true, agree.

Comment: @yoni you might look into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html, but again the only one specific instance will be defined, but in the external `META-INF/services/IMemoryCell` file, which is a little bit more flexible, but still limited to one specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way you could do that; interfaces are just that, interfaces.

They don't know who is implementing them, nor how to construct instances of arbitrary classes.

If you can guarantee a default constructor you could have a default interface method that calls `this.getClass().newInstance()`, e.g.,

```
default Interface1 buildMe() throws (etc...) {
  return getClass().newInstance();
}
```

But that has to be called on an instance already, which defeats the purpose.